# Discord.py grabbing twitch URL without an API

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have a discord bot.

What I want it to do is when the bot detects a user is streaming, print the URL of their stream into chat.

I'm having a problem trying to find out how to get the user's twitch channel url...

this is what I have

```
@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    aname = after.display_name
    aactivity = after.activity.type
    mactivity = str(after.activities)
    role = after.guild.get_role(736271867836498031)
    channel = client.get_channel(736269005651836985)
    memberinfo = after.activities.streaming.url
    print(memberinfo)
    if "Streaming name" in mactivity:
        await after.add_roles(role)
        await channel.send('{} has started streaming!'.format(after.display_name))
        print(aname + " is streaming!")
    else:
        await after.remove_roles(role)
        streamchannel = discord.Profile
        await channel.send('{} is not streaming!'.format(after.display_name))
        print(aname + " is not streaming.")
    print('member updated status')
```

Is there something I'm missing? I don't know how at all to either find the URL of the streamer, or get it from their connect accounts.

Answer (score 2):

[`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) objects have a [`Activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=activity#discord.Activity) attribute. You can check if `before.activity` or `after.activity` is an instance of the [`Streaming`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=streaming#discord.Streaming) class.
If so, the user either stopped or started streaming and we can send a message in `channel`:

```py
from discord import Streaming
from discord.utils import get

@client.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
    if not before.activity.type == after.activity.type:
        return

    role = get(after.guild.roles, id=736271867836498031)
    channel = get(after.guild.channels, id=736269005651836985)

    if isinstance(after.activity, Streaming):
        await after.add_roles(role)
        await channel.send(f"{before.mention} is streaming on {activity.platform}: {activity.name}.\nJoin here: {activity.url}")
    elif isinstance(before.activity, Streaming):
        await after.remove_roles(role)
        await channel.send(f'{after.mention} is no longer streaming!')
    else:
        return
```

**Reference:** [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)